# Mysql : can select dupes ok, how do i select the other data at same time?

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly sorry if the title is confusing, difficult to explain in one line!

ok, so i'm making a script to alert me of any potential duplicate rows in my db.

```
SELECT events.date, events.ven_id, COUNT(*)
FROM events    
GROUP BY events.date, events.ven_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

this successfully finds duplicate row, however only returns the `date` and `ven_id` columns, id like to get an `events.*` into the select statement somehow but still only return duplicate rows.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT events.date, events.ven_id, (select COUNT(*) events where date = ev.date and ven_id=ev.id) as eventcount
FROM events ev
GROUP BY events.date, events.ven_id 
where eventcount > 1
```

Comment: By the way.. an easier way would be to create a unique index.. trying to handle duplicates afterwards is ALWAYS a bad idea.. this should be done when inserting.. if you put a unique index on date+ven_id, a double should never be able to be inserted..

Comment: where does the 'ev' table come from?

Comment: the ev is an alias for "events" .. i have typed this without any syntax check since i don't have the database schema you are using but mysql does do aliases ( saying "select * from table tb" means that in the reset of your query, you can use "tb" which is an alias for "table" )

Comment: ok.. i've done a quick query on a table i have here and translated this back to the tablenames you are giving here. Try this and see if it gives the result you want: select date,ven_id,(select count(ven_id) from events where ven_id = ev.ven_id and date = ev.date) as eventcount from events ev where (select count(ven_id) from events where ven_id = ev.ven_id and date = ev.date) > 1